# Parted says external SD card has no partitions, but Android can still read it

Tags: external-sd, shell, samsung-galaxy-player

I have a 16GB external SD card that I'm currently using for my music collection. Android reads it just fine, and CWM mounts it perfectly. I'm on Gingerbread (I have my reasons).

I opened up `adb shell` and used `mount` to figure out where this SD card was mounted. It listed the SD card as being `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1`:
[image: mount results]

I opened this device up in parted (`parted /dev/block/mmcblk1p1`) and used `print` to find out what the partitions were on the device. To my surprise, it says there are... none:
[image: parted print results]

How is this possible? Android can mount it and read from it just fine, but parted apparently thinks there are no partitions on it. I get the same results when it's unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

you're just running parted wrong,
instead of

```
parted /dev/block/mmcblk1p1
```

it's

```
parted /dev/block/mmcblk1
```

and at the (parted) prompt

```
(parted) print all
```